# Stream a zip file into a variable with node.js zlib

Tags: javascript, node.js, unzip

I'm trying to unzip a local `zip` file into a variable in node.js like:

```
    var d;
    var fs = require('fs');
    var zlib = require('zlib');
    var zipPath='../../data/lemma/lemmatization-en.zip';
    var zipExists=fs.existsSync(zipPath);
    console.log(zipPath,zipExists);
    fs.createReadStream(zipPath)
    .on('data', function (data){
      d+=data.toString();
    })
    .on('end', function (){
      console.log("read",d.length);
        zlib.inflate(d, {},function(err, buf) {
            console.error(err)
            console.log("unzip",buf.toString());
        })
    })
```

the file is [here](http://www.lexiconista.com/Datasets/lemmatization-en.zip) and it is a regular zip archive.
When I run this I get a `Error: incorrect header check` error. I get the same error when trying to use pipe like:

```
    fs.createReadStream(zipPath)
    .pipe( zlib.createUnzip() )
    .on('data', function (data){
      d+=data.toString();
    })
    .on('end', function (){
      console.log("read",d.length);
    })
```

I'm aware that there are non native modules on `npm`, but I would like to keep it simple and use the `zlib` native module only.
My aim is to read the stream and load once into memory, since this file must be lazy loaded into the code at some point.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I have the same problem now...

Comment: In some way I did, I will check how